# how to randomly select an image from an arraylist using scanner in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to scan a folder of images and add them to an arraylist. I want to combine a scanner and random variable to randomly select one of the images from the array list and attach it to to a private ImageIcon icon. "FemaleFaces" is the directory with the images. So far, here is my code and thanks for any help!

```
private ImageIcon iconex; 

        File f = new File("FemaleFaces");
        Scan = new Scanner(f);
        ArrayList<ImageIcon> files = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();
        while(Scan.hasNext())
        {
            files.add(new ImageIcon(Scan.next()));
        }
        Scan.close();

        int Ffindex = new Random().nextInt(files.size());
        iconex = files.get(Ffindex);
```

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: FemaleFaces (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.(Unknown Source)
    at Human.(Human.java:66)
    at testerobjects.main(testerobjects.java:19)

Comment: Scan.next() will return a string. The string needs to be used to construct an ImageIcon object (using whatever logic you would use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scan.next()` returns a `String`.  You need to construct a `ImageIcon` from the value.

Something along the lines of...

```
files.add(new ImageIcon(Scan.next()));
```

Comment: Hi :) it now tells me the following error for some reason. I have updated them in the original post.

Comment: Where are the images stored?  Are the stored as flat files on the system some where or are the embedded within the Jar?

Comment: The images are stored in a folder that is in the Eclipse workspace folder along with the classes. Also, I've ran the scenario before with other txt files where I do same operation.

Comment: Try using `files.add(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(Scan.next())));` if that fails (with a `NullPointerException`, verify that the location of files compared with the values from the file...

Comment: Hey MadProgrammer, I tried that new statement but it still gives me the message that AccessDenied error. I moved the folder into another folder within the class which then tells me that it can't find it. So for sure it has located the folder but cannot access it. Weird huh?

Comment: Well, I don't use eclipse, but if I understand correctly, you're required to place embedded resources in the resource folder, which then get added to the Jar file when you build the application automatically.